# Type Coercion Error with Loaded and Instantiated SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, coercion

I am loading a swf, "ImageEdit" into another swf, "Shell". I instantiate ImageEdit with

```
var ClassReference:Class=imageEditApplicationDomain.getDefinition("ImageEdit") as Class;  
var instance:MovieClip=new ClassReference();
```

However, I get an error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@3b678b31 to fl.controls.Slider

ImageEdit does not throw an error when run by itself and not loaded into Shell. I've added:

```
import fl.controls.Slider
```

to Shell and other things which didn't help. Both SWFs contain the Slider component in their libraries. I am working Flash Professional CS5.5.

How can I get rid of the coercion error?

Comment: What code line does produce the error?

Comment: When ImageEdit gets instantiated and the stage is getting initialized i.e. before the ImageEdit class does anything so at the line "var instance:MovieClip=new ClassReference();"

Comment: Try to replace MovieClip with Sprite.

Comment: Thanks. That kinda works. It gets rid of that error, but subsequently in my code I get errors because it expects it to be of type MovieClip.  The coercion error does go away if remove the type from the variable declaration. So " public var slider_mc:Slider;" gives an error, but " public var slider_mc;" doesn't

Comment: So then I will add this as an answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace MovieClip with Sprite or * or leave the type out.